# polymer event between two child elements of parent

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I can add listener to event from child element at parent level. But how do I make one child listen to the event of another ? Is that possible or should I use parent as a mediator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to loosely couple components. [`iron-signals`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) is the one I am after.
All possible ways of communication is detailed [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/communication.html). Though its documented under 0.5 still seems to hold good for 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parent as mediator. Event binding is only supported between child and parent.